# Adding a License to your .Net Web Application

Tags: .net, asp.net, obfuscation

I am currently looking at adding some licensy type software which will protect my .net web application source code. Was wondering if you guys had any experience with this and knew perhaps any companies or sources which provide such utilities ?

So my main aim is to protect the actual files

i.e Default.aspx
Default.aspx.cs
....
being copied in the future without me being able to stop them from using it.

Thanks

EDIT : From reading the replies i seem to think obfuscator seems to be the way to go.
Does a obfuscator program only work on exe or dll's or does it also work on individual pages ?

Comment: Licensing software varies from country to country, in what country are you in?

Comment: its obfuscation, not protection, just so you know the terms :).

Comment: So is the only way they to protect your source code, using obfuscation ?

Comment: From reading the replies i seem to think obfuscator seems to be the way to go. Does a obfuscator program only work on exe or dll's or does it also work on individual pages ?

Answer (score 1):

One step you can do is to release it as a Web Application rather than a Web Site.

[Differences here from asp.net](http://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/archive/2008/07/13/differences-when-registering-httpmodules-and-httphandlers-for-web-application-projects-and-website-project.aspx)

As far as the Default.aspx, I don't know of a way to encrypt html pages that are served over standard web servers, and either way, the clients will all still be able to View Source, unless you write the entire page in JavaScript writes (horrible to manage).

Your best bet is to not include any application logic code what-so-ever in the aspx and compile your binaries using an obfusicator.

Comment: Is there no software where for example I can put a License on my code on the code which I can remove from the web app to make it unusable at any code.

Or is the only way to achieve is to use obfuscator and encrypt the pages ?

Comment: I'm not even sure you can encrypt the pages, but as far as I know, I don't think there is.

Answer (score 1):

I wondering if a simple pre-compile will do the trick in your ASP.NET application, we do that here in the company. We ship our Web modules pre-compiled and no one will see what's in the aspx code, all the "code-behind" files are translated into DLL's.

[see more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227976.aspx)

Comment: Is this like using the option in Visual Studio "Add as a web development Project".

Im wondering how easy this code is maintable during development etc ?

Comment: you need to generate and ship the entire web folder every time, but no one can look inside your code!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't bother with obfuscation: the latest *syntax-sugar*, compile-time tricks and optimisations in .Net 3.5 make simple reverse engineering pretty tough already.

For instance each time you use the `yield` keyword it generates an enumeration class with a complex structure and an unreadable name.

Obfuscation will make it tougher to reverse engineer, but not by a enough. Either will deter the basic hack with a copy of [reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/), neither will deter or stop a determined and expert cracker.

I would key-sign all your assemblies - then if they reverse one they have to reverse all.

I'd take as much of the actual application logic out of the web project and into referenced DLLs - your web project should really be all about the UI. This makes it easier to unit test the underlying logic, and easier to obfuscate if you decide that it's worth it.

Answer (score 0):

your web site can send to you some of the server machine information on each user login.
If the mechine information is wrong, cancel the login.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering if there was any other way to protect your sour code other than obfuscator or precompiling.

I.e you have a list of pages
Default.aspx
Default.aspx.cs
web.config

Where your main aim is to prevent a 3rd party from taking your code if they have access to the source code ?

Answer (score 0):

unless you obfuscate it in some way so it is more effort than it is worth, or you precompile I don't see how you could prevent them from just isolating the license checking code - and removing it.

You can run an obfuscator over the source code and distribute the obfuscated version, there are numerous examples of this around, particularly for javascript.

Comment: This would be in .net. So your saying the obfuscator can run on the actually code behind pages, so the web app does not need to be compilted into a DLL ?

Also lets say my pages are scrambled with obfuscator how do these work when they are run live ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing two different things here. One is law protection (that's what licences are for) and the other is physical protection. If everyone would obey law, then physical protection would not be needed.

I suggest you choose a licence that fits you (there are many of them), then take care of the physical protection in whatever way.